# Locate a sub-string with a general character '[a,z]-\n' and replace the non-general part of the sub-string '-\n'

Tags: r, regex, stringi

I have text I am cleaning up in R. I want to use stringi, but am happy to use other packages.

Some of the words are broken over two lines. So I get a sub-string "halfword-\nsecondhalfword".

I also have strings  that are just "----\nword" and "    -\n" (and some others that I do not want to replace.

What I want to do is identify all sub-strings "[a-z]-\n" and then keep the generic letter [a,z], but remove the -\n characters.

I do not want to remove all -\n , and I do not want to remove the letter [a-z].

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried word boundaries yet?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Make it easy for us to copy/paste the tests rather than extract them from your text.

Comment: Perhaps you just want `gsub("([a-z])-\n", "\\1", x)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may make use of word boundaries to match `-<LF>` only in between word characters:

```
gsub("\\b-\n\\b", "", x)
gsub("(*UCP)\\b-\n\\b", "", x, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(x, "\\b-\n\\b", "", x)
```

The latter two support word boundaries between any Unicode word characters.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OAShrJ/1).

If you want to only remove `-<LF>`  between letters you may use

```
gsub("([a-zA-Z])-\n([a-zA-Z])", "\\1\\2", x)
gsub("(\\p{L})-\n(\\p{L})", "\\1\\2", x, perl=TRUE)
stringr::str_replace_all(x, "(\\p{L})-\n(\\p{L})", "\\1\\2")
```

If you need to only support lowercase letters, remove `A-Z` in the first `gsub` and replace `\p{L}` with `\p{Ll}` in the latter two.

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OAShrJ/2).